# Magento how to get search product always come on first in result

Tags: magento

I want to get search product come always first position on result.

for ex. 
My search product is **Chocolate Rabbit Father Set** but it is coming at 8th position.

before this some products are coming like Chocolate Rabbit Grandparents, Chocolate Rabbit Baby, Milk Rabbit Baby so more...

is there any suggestion how to come search product will always come on first position.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain how are you searching? Is it SQL query? if yes then share it so one can answer you.

Comment: I used both search type 'Fulltext' and' Like'..

Comment: @vipul Hadiya: I used magento search functionality..